# ¿Se puede crear varios "models.py" en un proyecto de django y hacer una relación entre dos tablas en diferentes DB´s?

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-models

desde hace poco he venido trabajando con Django 1.11, Python 3.6 y SQL Server 2012 para los modelos del proyecto. Actualmente tengo esto en el archivo Settings.py:

**Settings.py > DATABASES**

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'Campañas_BI',
    'USER': 'jflorian',
    'PASSWORD': '******',
    'HOST': '##.##.##.##\instancia',
    'PORT': '',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
    },
},

'default2': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'Informes_Comerciales',
    'USER': 'jflorian',
    'PASSWORD': '******',
    'HOST': '##.##.##.##\instancia',
    'PORT': '',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
    },
},
```

Utilicé el comando `python manage.py inspectdb --database=default > modelsCampanasBI.py` y `python manage.py inspectdb --database=default2 > modelsInformesComerciales.py` para crear los modelos de cada base de datos.

Y mi pregunta es, ¿tengo que crear un archivo `models.py` con las tabas que necesito de cada base de datos o utilizo los archivos que creé con las lineas anteriores?

Si la respuesta es que debo utilizar los archivos `modelsCampanasBI.py`, `modelsInformesComerciales.py`, cómo debería registrar los modelos en mi archivo `admin.py`

Por otro lado, tengo que crear una relación entre dos tablas (`foreign key`), el problema es que cada tabla está en diferentes bases de datos. ¿Alguna sugerencia para realizar esta relación utilizando django o SQL Server?

Agradezco mucho sus respuestas.